# Using Reflection for finding deprecation

Tags: c#, t4

I am curious if anyone has written any code to reflect into a class and find its Deprecated methods?

Ive whipped a T4 Template for reactive and would love to have it stop generating handlers for deprecated events, any clever hackers out there that already beat me to the punch?

Comment: Are you using reflection with T4? This is [not recommended](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/how-to-use-t4-to-generate-decorator-classes/).

Comment: Do you mean members marked as Obsolete (is that part of the reactive framework?)

Comment: Modified a T4 Template to generate Observables out of the UI delegates and it would pick up the Deprecated events, I just needed to filter them out at generation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if you're asking for t4 framework or not but here's a generic reflection sample for Obsolete flagged methods.

```
class TestClass
{
    public TestClass()
    {
        DeprecatedTester.FindDeprecatedMethods(this.GetType());
    }

    [Obsolete("SomeDeprecatedMethod is deprecated, use SomeNewMethod instead.")]
    public void SomeDeprecatedMethod() { }

    [Obsolete("YetAnotherDeprecatedMethod is deprecated, use SomeNewMethod instead.")]
    public void YetAnotherDeprecatedMethod() { }

    public void SomeNewMethod() { }        
}

public class DeprecatedTester
{
    public static void FindDeprecatedMethods(Type t)
    {
        MethodInfo[] methodInfos = t.GetMethods();

        foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methodInfos)
        {
            object[] attributes = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false);

            foreach (ObsoleteAttribute attribute in attributes.OfType<ObsoleteAttribute>())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found deprecated method: {0} [{1}]", methodInfo.Name, attribute.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, GetCustomAttributes() is overloaded and can take a type parameter. So to check if a method is deprecated, you just pass `typeof(ObsoleteAttribute)`. The checker I'm using (for enum values) is:

    `return obj.GetType().GetField(obj.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ObsoleteAttribute), true).Length > 0;`